# Vue2 Composition API Apollo client with id default not found

Tags: vuejs2, apollo, apollo-client, vue-composition-api, vue-apollo

I have started having an issue with apollo client in vue2 when using inside a watch.
I have followed the setup guide for apollo client when using the composition api:

https://v4.apollo.vuejs.org/guide-composable/setup.html#_2-connect-apollo-client-to-vue

so my `main.ts` looks like this:

```ts
    import contentfulClient from "./plugins/vue-apollo-contentful";
    import apiClient from "./plugins/vue-apollo-api";

    Vue.config.productionTip = false;

    Vue.use(VueApollo);

    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      vuetify,
      setup() {
        provide(ApolloClients, {
          default: apiClient,
          apiClient,
          contentfulClient,
        });
      },
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount("#app");
```

The clients have their own files and are `setup` the same:

```ts
    import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
    import { createHttpLink } from "apollo-link-http";
    import { InMemoryCache } from "apollo-cache-inmemory";

    const uri = `https://graphql.contentful.com/content/v1/spaces/${process.env.VUE_APP_CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID}/environments/${process.env.VUE_APP_CONTENTFUL_ENV}?access_token=${process.env.VUE_APP_CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN}`;
    const link = createHttpLink({
      uri,
    });
    const cache = new InMemoryCache();

    const contentfulClient = new ApolloClient({
      link,
      cache,
    });

    export default contentfulClient;
```

I have this component:

```ts
    import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref, watch } from "@vue/composition-api";

    import { useGetCategory } from "@/logic/get-category";

    export default defineComponent({
      name: "Categories",
      setup(_, context) {
        const slug = ref(context.root.$route.params.slug);
        const result = ref({});

        const getCategory = (slug) => {
          console.log(slug);
          const { category, loading, error } = useGetCategory(slug);
          result.value = { category, loading, error };
        };

        watch(() => context.root.$route.params.slug, getCategory);
        onMounted(() => getCategory(slug.value));

        return { result };
      },
    });
```

When this component loads, it "gets the category" by executing this:

```ts
    import { useQuery, useResult } from "@vue/apollo-composable";
    import * as getCategoryBySlug from "@/graphql/api/query.category.gql";

    export function useGetCategory(slug: string) {
      const { result, loading, error } = useQuery(getCategoryBySlug, { slug });
      const category = useResult(result, null, (data) => data.getCategoryBySlug);
      return { category, loading, error };
    }
```

When the page loads, it gets the category fine, but if I change the route parameter (slug) I expect it to get the new category and display it. But instead I get this error:

[image]

So I figured that the setup is wrong in **main.ts**, so I added the **non-composition-api** aswell, found here:

https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html#_1-apollo-client

Now my **main.ts** looks like this:

```ts
    import contentfulClient from "./plugins/vue-apollo-contentful";
    import apiClient from "./plugins/vue-apollo-api";

    Vue.config.productionTip = false;

    const apolloProvider = new VueApollo({
      defaultClient: apiClient,
    });

    Vue.use(apolloProvider);

    new Vue({
      router,
      store,
      vuetify,
      apolloProvider,
      setup() {
        provide(ApolloClients, {
          default: apiClient,
          apiClient,
          contentfulClient,
        });
      },
      render: (h) => h(App),
    }).$mount("#app");
```

But this does not work. It compiles, but I still get the same error.
Does anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is

```
  setup() {
    provide(DefaultApolloClient, apolloClient);
  },
```